# Set password on cronjob

Tags: cron, gitlab

So i searched a bit and didn't find answers
I'm trying a cronjob for the first time and i'm trying to push to my Gitlab repository on a determined daily time
I'm trying something like:

```
10 10 * * * cd/repofolder && git push && login && password
```

The thing is it works only until the git push command, then login and password are not being typed on the cron job
How do i make the cronjob also type the login and password when the Gitlab asks for it?

Comment: You should store your public SSH key in GitLab so it doesn't ask for login and password in the first place.

Comment: Also, I think there is a space missing after `cd`, no?

Comment: i'm having some (permission denied) problem with SSH ( which i didn't have yesterday), so for now i kinda want to do this with HTTP, i know the only problem is the login and password because i receive a mail telling me the error

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having some (permission denied) problem with SSH ( which i didn't have yesterday),

Check with which account your root command is executed: root or your own?
Because the cron job will look for ~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub) keys in the HOME folder. Make sure the provate key is not passphrase protected.

> so for now i kinda want to do this with HTTP,

Then make sure the credentials are cached, through a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage). That way, you don't have to enter any credentials. (Again, beware of the account used).

Comment: thanks man i actually fixed it using SSH, i would just like to know now if there is a way for the cronjob to type the password